# how to pass js variable in the ajax link function

Tags: php, javascript, yii

How to pass the studentID in the URL? Since its js variable am getting error or its passed as string.

```
<script>    
    function updateCallhistory(studentID)
    {  
        <?php   
            echo CHtml::ajax(array(
            'url'=> Yii::app()->createUrl("siteiq/UpdateStudentForm", array("ClassID" => $ClassID) ),           
            'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
            'type'=>'post',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>"function(data)
            {
            if (data.status == 'failure')
            {
                $('#dialogStudentForm div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                  // Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                $('#dialogStudentForm div.divForForm form').submit(updateCallhistory);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dialogStudentForm div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                setTimeout(\"$('#dialogStudentForm').dialog('close') \",1000);
            }

            } ",
        ))?>;
        return false;  
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: function updateCallhistory(studentID) Is this a php or a js function?

Comment: Sorry its JS function. I have edited my question

Comment: Which is php variable in this code???

Comment: so... you're calling js function to call php code to echo js code? This doesn't sound right...

Comment: What do you mean by "it is passed as string"? If you want it in a URL, it will be always string, since URLs are texts. And what is problem with being string? PHP handles types very vague anyway.

Comment: If i add the studentID var in the ajax url 
  'url'=> Yii::app()->createUrl("siteiq/UpdateCallHistory", array("ClassID" => $ClassID,"studentID" => "js:studentID") ),           
  am getting the url like 
  "POST index.php/siteiq/UpdateStudentForm?ClassID=3&studentID=js%3AstudentID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<script>    
    function updateCallhistory(studentID)
    {  

        var url = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("siteiq/UpdateStudentForm", array("ClassID" => $ClassID) ); ?>' + '&studentID='+studentID;
        <?php   
            echo CHtml::ajax(array(
            'url'=> 'js:url',           
            'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
            'type'=>'post',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>"function(data)
            {
            if (data.status == 'failure')
            {
                $('#dialogStudentForm div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                  // Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                $('#dialogStudentForm div.divForForm form').submit(updateCallhistory);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dialogStudentForm div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                setTimeout(\"$('#dialogStudentForm').dialog('close') \",1000);
            }

            } ",
        ))?>;
        return false;  
    }
    </script>
```